# Authentication with ASP.NET MVC site and ServiceStack API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC with an API using ServiceStack.

Very soon I want to add authentication.  The website will have at least two types of users 'service providers' and 'service consumers', although a user could have multiple roles.

I am open to using new MVC Identity, but I want whatever I use to work nicely for both the servicestack API and MVC 'pages' that don't necessarily use the API but should show different content based on login. I do not want to **require** javascript for login/logout.

I would like the solution to use tokens as I have not used session state anywhere else, but I am open to other options providing they would scale horizontally on a cloud provider (users next request may go to a different instance of back-end).

Anyone have example of an ideal solution?

(N.B: I am not interested in an externally hosted service).

Comment: (I know about ServiceStack authentication and I have used it for a SPA API, but have not integrated with ASP.NET MVC or tokenised it before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack's Authentication can also be used by external ASP.NET Web Frameworks, the [ServiceStack and MVC Integration docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) shows how you can [accept Login credentials from a MVC Controller and register them with ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration#using-resolveservice-to-call-services-directly):

```
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, string redirect=null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var authService = ResolveService<AuthenticateService>())
            {
                var response = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate {
                    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
                    UserName = userName,
                    Password = password,
                    RememberMe = true,
                });

                // add ASP.NET auth cookie
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);

                return Redirect(string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirect) ? "/" : redirect);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return View("Index", GetViewModel());
}
```

The http://mvc.servicestack.net Live Demo shows an example of calling this controller using a standard MVC HTML Form.

Your MVC Controllers can then inherit ServiceStackController to access the Authenticated Users Session and different ServiceStack providers, here are the API's relating to Session and Authentication:

```
public class ServiceStackController : Controller
{
    //...
    ISession SessionBag { get; set; }
    bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    IAuthSession GetSession(bool reload = true);
    TUserSession SessionAs<TUserSession>();
    void ClearSession();
}
```

#### Enable OAuth Providers

Should you need to you can also [enable ServiceStack's different OAuth providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration#using-servicestack-oauth-in-mvc) which can optionally callback either directly to a ServiceStack Service or

Comment: I was of course hoping for you to answer, I've put a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180162/is-there-a-way-to-authorise-servicestack-with-asp-net-identity

Comment: @Darren Couldn't tell you, never used ASP.NET Identity so not sure what the appropriate integration strategy would be. Don't have time to R&D myself, but some approaches I'd explore include a custom AuthProvider that's expected to be called via MVC in an OnAuthentication callback, if that's not possible another approach is to manually save a `AuthUserSession` in ServiceStack's Session yourself, you may also need to manually set ServiceStack's `ss-id` / `ss-pid` cookies on the Response yourself as Identity is based on OWIN instead of the ASP.NET context so any cookies SS sets might be ignored.

Comment: if you have 3 mins look at what I added below, perhaps I don't need/want **GeType().Name** in there.

Comment: @Darren it's ok, the OperationName is basically metadata to identify the name of the Request DTO, it's not used in Views.

Answer (score 1):

Further to mythz answer I also needed to know if a user was authenticated in a view and the normal Request.IsAuthenticated does not work when your doing above.  So I created a CustomWebViewPage (to use this you will have to change ***pageBaseType="Your.NameSpace.CustomWebViewPage"** in the View folder's Web.config).

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    private IServiceStackProvider _serviceStackProvider;
    public virtual IServiceStackProvider ServiceStackProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceStackProvider ?? (_serviceStackProvider =
                new ServiceStackProvider(new AspNetRequest(base.Context, GetType().Name)));
        }
    }

    public virtual bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return ServiceStackProvider.IsAuthenticated; }
    }
}

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    //EXACTLY the same as above method...
```